# Secret Key Generator Change on Click in Android Pie

Tags: java, android, encryption

The following code to generate a secret key changes in every click to generate. I can't find the error, using android pie emulator is not working properly. Please help.

```java
    public static String encrypt(String seed,String cleartext) throws Exception{
        byte[] rawkey= getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result=encrypt(rawkey,cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);  
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception{
        KeyGenerator kGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr;
       // sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kGen.init(128,sr);
        SecretKey sKey = kGen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = sKey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt (byte[] raw,byte[] clear) throws Exception{
        SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(raw,"AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,skeyspec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: The key value change in every click event. old version emulator key value display single for many click never changes but the new version change every click . how to find that problem .

Comment: Please post the code that runs in every click event.